# xslt ignore comments when testing position

Tags: xml, xslt, comments, saxon

How do I write XSLT so that the processor ignores comments when calculating the position of other elements?

I expect that the XSLT processor will filter out comments before applying the other template rules, but with a comment after the last list item, the test `not(position()=last())` fails.
How can I remove the comments before that test?

XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                                                                                                                       
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">                                                                                                                                  
  <ul>                                                                                                                                                                       
    <li>fish1</li>                                                                                                                                                           
    <li>fish2</li>                                                                                                                                                           
    <li>fish3</li>                                                                                                                                                           
    <li>fish4</li>                                                                                                                                                           
    <!--                                                                                                                                                                     
      <li>fish5</li>                                                                                                                                                         
    -->                                                                                                                                                                      
  </ul>                                                                                                                                                                      
</html>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                                                                                                                       
<xsl:stylesheet                                                                                                                                                              
  version="2.0"                                                                                                                                                              
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"                                                                                                                                 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                             
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" indent="no" />                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                             
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                             
  <xsl:template match="comment()" />                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                 
  <xsl:template match="/">                                                                                                                                                   
    <xsl:apply-templates />                                                                                                                                                  
  </xsl:template>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  <xsl:template match="xhtml:ul">                                                                                                                                            
    <xsl:apply-templates />                                                                                                                                                  
  </xsl:template>                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                             
  <xsl:template match="xhtml:li">                                                                                                                                            
    <xsl:apply-templates />                                                                                                                                                  
    <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">                                                                                                                                   
      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>                                                                                                                                                
    </xsl:if>                                                                                                                                                                
  </xsl:template>                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                             
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output with `SaxonJ-HE` 12.1:

```
fish1, fish2, fish3, fish4,
```

Comment: That's going to be a parameter to the parser.  If you are writing in Java for example that would be `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory#setIgnoringComments(true)`.  If you're running a command-line XSLT processor check the parameters for that processor.

Comment: Also note that XSLT 2 and later have a `separator` attribute on `xsl:value-of` so the easiest approach for the wanted output would be to use e.g. `<xsl:template match="xhtml:ul"><xsl:value-of select="xhtml:li" separator=", "/></xsl:template>`. Not on answer on ignoring comment but perhaps helpful.

Comment: Even better, make it `<xsl:template match="/xhtml:html"><xsl:value-of select="xhtml:ul/xhtml:li" separator=", "/></xsl:template>`. Then you can get rid of all your other templates without worrying about text from some other node being copied to the output.

Comment: @musarithmia I don't see why `xsl:value-of` would not work for inserting *any* string between the items of *any* sequence. If your example does not represent your actual situation, then post a better one. Preferably in a new question - I believe this one has been answered.

Comment: @musarithmia I don't see the point in this discussion. As you say, your question was about excluding the comment nodes from the processed sequence, and at least 2 of the answers answered it as such. I still suspect `xsl:value-of` could be used to simplify the process, but without a representative example that's all I can say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace `test="not(position()=last())"` with `test="following-sibling::*"`.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#applying-templates:

> The xsl:apply-templates instruction takes as input a sequence of nodes ...
>
> The default value of the select attribute is child::node(), which
> causes all the children of context node to be processed.

To exclude the comment node from the selected sequence, change this:

```
  <xsl:template match="xhtml:ul">                                                                                                                                            
    <xsl:apply-templates />                                                                                                                                                  
  </xsl:template>
```

to:

```
  <xsl:template match="xhtml:ul">                                                                                                                                            
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />                                                                                                                                                  
  </xsl:template>
```

---

Note that you can remove the first two templates.

Answer (score 0):

I have a general rule of thumb when writing XSLT which is to favour writing XPath expressions over writing XSLT elements (which I try to keep to a minimum). Applying this rule to your stylesheet would yield something like this:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" indent="no" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join(//xhtml:li, ', ')">
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT's templating and pattern-matching features are powerful, but in this case they are far more powerful than you need.

All you really need here is just the XPath expression `string-join(//xhtml:li, ', ')`, and the XSLT I wrote is just a simple wrapper for that.

Comment: I tend to offer precisely the opposite advice. Here either `select='*'` or Michael's change of the test would be my preference. The problem with using `string-join` is that it's going to ignore inline markup in the list items (em, code, i, b, span, etc.)

Comment: The OP is generating plain text, so other markup isn't relevant. That's one reason why a "pure XPath" solution is more appropriate, in my opinion.

Comment: All too often, I've found stylesheets which took that approach, used XPath expressions and constructions like string-join all over, and then someone says, "hey, wait, we want `code` or `em` or `a` to be allowed in those places" and now you're looking at a tedious job replacing all those expressions. Use the power of XSLT to your advantage, don't work around it :-)

Comment: well as it turns out, the questioner's example doesn't really accurately represent their actual case, so my suggestion doesn't apply. But I think for cases where people really are simply extracting some plain text values, my suggested approach really is appropriate; it's a matter of recognising where that's the case.